# How can a texture image be wrapped onto a large object without seeing a pattern?

Tags: uv

I have a very long object (15 metres) and want to make it look like a cement slab. I have a number of texture images for concrete which I have 'wrapped' onto the object which at first look completely stretched and so I tried applying scale eg S25 which gets rid of the stretched image look but results in a pattern showing as it seems that the texture image is repeated along the length of the object. Is there a method to use a texture image (most of which represent a close up view of the concrete) on a very large object and get it to look like (say) concrete.
[image]

[image]

Comment: An entirely procedural material or a custom mapping solution such as https://youtu.be/-VgtSL5ZpYc are both good remedies.

Comment: Thanks. The video tutorial looks great and will resolve my 'problem'. I thought 'seamless' images would prevent it happening but not. Thanks again

Comment: In the strictest sense, there are no "seamless" textures. Seamless, in the context of textures just means that the edges will have no obvious or harsh breaks when tiled i.e. the opposite edges will blend into each other when tiled, but there's no perfect solution for the tiling in the end.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned in the comments, fixed textures will never be free of tiling and UV headaches. Procedural generation not only relieves your tiling problem, but any unwrapping inconsistencies as well. Lucky for you, procedural concrete isn't that complicated - just a bunch of Noise, really ;)

Consider this a learning example:

[image: Concrete]

I'll put the file here so you don't have to recreate the graph.

File is here - [image]

Comment: Thanks again Christopher. I have never worked with 'nodes' and a quick look indicates to me that you didn't use a texture image just a basic color and then 'did things with it' (sorry as my knowledge of nodes is virtually nil I am guessing). I must point out that as my model (of the floating docks at Vancouver harbor for float planes) will never be 'viewed' from closer than (say) 2 metres (the view from the inside of a floatplane) texture/roughness doesn't have much 'value'. Anyway it's a great way of seeing what can be done and thanks again.

Comment: Correct. Blender comes with several procedurally generated texture "presets" that are available from the `Add > Texture` menu available in the midbar section. These "textures" are not based on any image and are instead generated through mathematical equations. As a result of this, the textures are infinitely scalable without loss of resolution, and are also able to keep a "randomness" to the pattern that never repeats. The texture I made use of  primarily in this graph is the Noise Texture. If you plan on using shading nodes, make friends with  it - it's good for _a lot_ of things.

Comment: If you need the texture to be viewable from farther away (less detailed), just reduce the Scale of all the noise textures except the bottom left one. A good place to start is to cut each value in half (ie 160 becomes 80). Do it with the top Voronoi texture as well.

Comment: I also meant to mention that it looks as if it would take some time to do what you did and I applaud you for doing that. I wonder if I can somehow use that blender file to incorporate into my blender project to save me the time of (trying to) recreate it?

Comment: Select the cube from my file and copy it (Ctrl + C). then, open another blender file (your file perhaps) and paste it into the viewport (Ctrl + V). You now have that material in the new file. You can apply it to something else, and then delete the cube.

Comment: Also, if you want a fast way to make the texture "larger" (and I can't believe I didn't think of this before), just connect the "Generated" Texture Coordinate to everywhere I have "Object" connected (replace the connection). It's possible this may cause some stretching, but it also could be fine. Won't know till you try :)

Comment: Hi Chris,  I copied the material from your cube and applied it to my 'floating concrete dock' but found the overall effect to be darker than I would like. I then went back to your cube and dragged the sliders on every slider I could find (all colorRamp nodes) (towards the white 'end' and still could not get a lighter 'shade'. What do I need to do? Sorry I have never used nodes before.  Thanks

Comment: Don't worry about that -  Either add a Hue/Saturation/Value node right before the basecolor and  increase the value OR add a Bright/Contrast Node in the same place and increase the brightness.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127096/discussion-between-john-arnold-and-christopher-bennett).

Comment: Christopher sorry for resurrecting this thread/question.   I have forgotten how to apply the nodes you created to my docks.  I open your blender file and copy the cube (Ctrl C) from the viewport then open my blender file and paste it into the viewport. I then go to the node view (select shading) drag mouse around all the procedural nodes and copy (Ctrl C)  select my object go to node view, delete existing nodes then paste (Ctrl V).  I can then see all the nodes you created.  I return to layout and I cannot see the effect. Please sort me out. Thanks

Comment: I think that once you paste the cube into your file, it should automatically add the material (named "Concrete") to your list of "available materials". This list can be accessed by clicking the colored button represented by a globe and a down arrow next to the material name in the material properties tab. Just select the object you want the material on, go to material properties, click that button (browse materials) and select concrete form the list. It will replace whatever material you currently have in the material slot for that object.

Comment: Also, if you still can't see it in the viewport, make sure you are in Material Preview or Rendered Preview mode (Z button opens the selection pie menu).

Comment: Thanks Christopher. When I 'browsed material to be selected (lmb the downwards pointing arrow) and the list of available materials was displayed, I then selected concrete. As easy as that. I can't remember doing it that way before. Anyway this is probably the correct way. Thanks again. Something else (browse material) I have learned.

Comment: Christopher, I can't export the node material but rather than continue a discussion here posted a new question 'Node materials not seen in Microsoft Flight Simulator"